# How to install DroidCam?

Tags: camera

I tried to follow this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qI7_w-NDKmo). I do not have install in the directory droidcam.

Error after advice:

[image]

Comment: please describe what the video tells you to do ... questions need to be self contained ... the link to the video can become stale ... also, please explain what you have done and include any error messages (as text, not picture of text)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The installation instruction is available on [dev47apps.com](https://www.dev47apps.com/droidcam/linux/)

```
sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r) gcc make v4l2loopback-dkms v4l2loopback-utils
sudo modprobe -v v4l2loopback
cd /tmp/
wget -O droidcam_latest.zip https://files.dev47apps.net/linux/droidcam_1.7.2.zip
unzip droidcam_latest.zip -d droidcam
cd droidcam 
sudo ./install-client
droidcam
```

The error:

```
Droidcam/v4l2loopback device not found '/dev/video[0-9]).
Did it install correctly?
If you had a kernel update, you may need to re-install.
```

can be fixed by loading the kernel module `v4l2loopback.ko`: `sudo modprobe -v v4l2loopback`.

Comment: Thank you, I got an error like in previous attempts. I added it to my question.

Comment: @ElenaGreg You are welcome. You need to load the `v4l2loopback` through `sudo modprobe -v v4l2loopback`. See my edit.